# auto sort and resize to images in the gallery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a gallery and I want it to be dynamically sorted and resized (with the original ratio). In the end of the post I added a picture that describe what I want.

Right now I have this code that includes array with all the photos and the code thet should display them:

```
<?php
    $works = array(
        1 => array("Chill", "elenby", "http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2014/008/f/4/chill_by_elenby-d71g75m.jpg", "http://isrart.co.il/showthread.php?t=12072"),
        2 => array("Fenix", "Elis", "http://ufu.co.il/files/aydw724j81kcd2zx3az0.jpg", "http://isrart.co.il/showthread.php?t=12070"),
        3 => array("Dont panic", "Tzah", "http://oi41.tinypic.com/vwrjly.jpg", "http://isrart.co.il/showthread.php?t=12084"),
        4 => array("Summer Jam", "elenby", "http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2014/003/7/3/summer_jam_by_elenby-d70q8sy.jpg", "http://isrart.co.il/showthread.php?t=12052"),
        5 => array("Ancient Facts", "Dangle", "http://isrart.co.il/attachment.php?attachmentid=4173&d=1388471618", "http://isrart.co.il/showthread.php?t=12032"),
        6 => array("SAVIOR", "daskull", "http://25.media.tumblr.com/c8d55b4371ad32250129e4e1aae530b6/tumblr_mzf8alBIOe1s4jk9mo1_1280.png", "http://isrart.co.il/showthread.php?t=12106"),
        7 => array("BFF", "roni yoffe", "http://isrart.co.il/attachment.php?attachmentid=4211&d=1389791848", "http://isrart.co.il/showthread.php?t=12108"),
        8 => array("New York City", "ChananGrenblatt", "https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/1492578_244031302429143_693411241_o.jpg", "http://isrart.co.il/showthread.php?t=12090"),
        9 => array("Envato", "impact", "http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/005/7/2/envato_by_impact_design-d70ylnm.png", "http://isrart.co.il/showthread.php?t=12068"),
        10 => array("Crismes", "Tali", "http://ufu.co.il/files/i7ehgj692t5i3m6txrv0.jpg", "http://isrart.co.il/showthread.php?t=12031")
    );
    $date = "January 2014";
?> 

<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $date; ?></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="author" content="Vlad Gincher">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bestofthemonth.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body">
            <img src="isrart.png" alt="Isrart" title="<?php echo $date; ?>" /><br />
            <h1><?php echo $date; ?></h1>
            <div>
                <?php
                for ($i = 1; $i < count($works); $i++){
                    echo '
                        <div id="work'.$i.'">
                            <img src="'.$works[$i][2].'" alt="" />
                        </div>
                    ';
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the picture (In the code I'll have much less images):
[image: How I want it to be like]

Comment: sort and resize based on what rules? also - show us what have you tried already. Nobody will write it for you. And bear in mind this going to be quite complicated anyway.

Comment: @LorDex It's hard to me to explain you because I'm bad in English. I added a photo with how I want the gallery will look like. I want that there won't be white spaces and the images to resize but stay with the same ratio, if possible. If not, so as close as the code will be able to the original ratio.

Comment: So, you're looking to fill all available space with the images in the array?

Comment: I understand, but you have to realize, if script is going to resize and arrange images, it needs to have some specification - you cannot just tell the script "resize and arrange so all of them will cover the container in 100%" - this is not how it works

Comment: @DrydenLong if it is possible, yes.

Comment: @LorDex so what can I tell him? I want him to randomly resize and order the images. If it will help, I can add to the array numbers that will order the images by their importance so the best images will be big and the other will be smaller.

Comment: Ok, I'd start by looking into the Mosaic Flow plug-in for jQuery... http://sapegin.github.io/jquery.mosaicflow/

Comment: as far as i know, mosaic does not resize - just arrange based on items' sizes. There's another one called masonry. you can check it out as well

Comment: @LorDex good point, I'm not sure if it does or not either. If OP wants his images randomly resized, he could always apply a random scale factor to the images before the Mosaic plug-in does its magic...

Comment: @DrydenLong this is an idea, but I'm 100% sure that randomly resized images would never fill the cointainer in 100%. Here's my idea - create static grind with layout you presented above. Try to process each image with aspect ratio CLOSE to each cell, then size (and possibly trim each image slightly). IMO that's the only solution that will work.

Comment: Something like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com)

Comment: @LorDex But I have no idea how to do it :|

Comment: @LorDex I guess it depends on how "randomly" you resize them. Assuming the height of the container is irrelevant, get the width of the container, use random percentages as the new width of the images until you reach 100% and repeat for each "row" I'm going to play with this and see if I can't make it work...

Comment: @DrydenLong I have an idea how to randomly resize. using `random(4,6)` (Php or Js)  it will return the number of the images in each cloumb and then it will randomly divide it (20%, 35%, 10%, 25%, 10%) and the height will be on `auto`. Does it is possible?

Comment: @VladGincher That is what I was thinking. Combine the resizing you just mentioned and the Mosaic (or similar) plug-in and you should be good... My only suggestion would be when resizing the images, make sure that their final sizes add up to 100% so you don't have awkward gaps

Comment: @DrydenLong can you halp me with that?

Comment: @VladGincher I'm Working on something now

Comment: Ok, so after working on this for a while and then re-reading your question, it looks like Mosaic, Masonry, etc will do what you want natively. All these plugins resize the images for you so you shouldn't need to resize them yourself first... Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: You can also try D3.js in order to work on it: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582 . I guess that with some hacks in this example you can build something by instead to print divs print img's

Answer (score 0):

As used in this solution?

[Demo](http://www.ryanepp.com/demos/balanced_gallery/horizontal)

[Tutorial](https://github.com/repp/BalancedGallery)